# How to speed up plotting of q-Gamma function

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, special-functions

I want to plot [q-gamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-GammaFunction.html) in 3D

I tried :

```
Plot3D[QGamma[x, q], {x, -2, 2}, {q, -0.5, 0.5}]
```

but there is no result.

2D works very fast...

```
Plot[QGamma[x, 1/2], {x, -2, 2}, PlotTheme -> "Web"]
```

[image]

There is a low resolution  graphic from [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot3D%5BQGamma%5Bx,+q%5D,+%7Bx,+-2,+2%7D,+%7Bq,+-0.5,+0.5%7D%5D)

[image]

Comment: Try `Plot3D[QGamma[x, q], {x, -2, 2}, {q, -1/2, 1/2}, MaxRecursion -> 2, Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> 145]`.

Comment: @J.M. but there is [no graphic](http://imgur.com/i9oUaF0) for $q<0$.

Comment: Well, what does `Plot[QGamma[x, -1/2], {x, -2, 2}]` look like, for instance? Are you sure it's always real in that region? Did you notice the "Real Part" notation in the picture you posted? Have you seen `Re[]`?

Comment: @J.M. its real for positive integers $x$ `Table[QGamma[x, -1/2], {x, 1, 10}]`,  but.. why there is a result in [wolframaplha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot3D%5BQGamma%5Bx,+q%5D,+%7Bx,+-2,+2%7D,+%7Bq,+-0.5,+0.5%7D%5D) ?

Comment: For integer $x$, sure. What about real $x$?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to stem from a misunderstanding of the underlying math, rather than from a MMA problem.

Comment: @MarcoB sorry I am not mathematician.  I'm only dentist ))) and my question isn't about mathematics. I wanted to know how to plot the given function !!

Comment: @vito No apology needed! I'm not a mathematician myself :-) Closing a question has more to do with site cleanup and management, and does not necessarily reflect on the quality of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Plot3D[#,
    {x, -2, 2}, {q, -1/2, 1/2},
    PlotLabel -> Style[Head[#], 14, Bold],
    ClippingStyle -> None,
    ImageSize -> 300,
    PlotPoints -> 75] & /@
  ReIm[QGamma[x, q]] // Column
```

[image]

Comment: why  `Re` not work instead of `ReIm` for $q<0$. `Plot3D[#, {x, -2, 2}, {q, -1/2, 1/2}, 
   PlotLabel -> Style[Head[#], 14, Bold], ClippingStyle -> None, 
   ImageSize -> 300, PlotPoints -> 75, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"] & /@
  Re[QGamma[x, q]]` ?

Comment: @vito - Because `Re[QGamma[x, q]]` is not a list. Use `Plot3D[Re[QGamma[x, q]], {x, -2, 2}, {q, -1/2, 1/2}, 
 PlotLabel -> Style[Re, 14, Bold], ClippingStyle -> None, 
 ImageSize -> 300, PlotPoints -> 75, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]`

Comment: Halton  +1. thanks